# How to stop drag and drop functionality for some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jstree

can we stop drag and drop for some item I have fiddle in which user can drag and drop to any play .
can we stop some element which having ID starting from "not" ?I am using jstree in my demo .I want user can drag and drop any element but prevent those id which is started from "not"
here is my fiddle ?

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/50/

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    alert("node_children: " + data.node.children);
    $('#tree').jstree(true).toggle_node(data.node); 


                                                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple workaround:

```
$('#tree').on('mousedown touchstart', 'li[id^=not] a', function(e){
    $(this)[e.type === "mousedown" ? "mouseup" : "touchend"]();
});
```

### DEMO

Comment: if I am using for mobile device  .so what I use touchmove ?

Comment: or maybe touchstart and trigger touchend, not sure about that. That's said, maybe jsTree plugin handle the case where you can unable drag for specific element, i absolutely don't know this plugin, maybe chek in DOC if this kind of option exists

Comment: can you please look out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472302/how-to-get-node-selected-information-using-jquery